# Created new nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested model

```
resources: customers do
  resources: readings
end
```

I am trying to create a new Customer reading. My new action in the Readings Controller is

```
#GET /customers/:customer_id/readings/new
def new
#1st you retrieve the customer
 customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
#2nd you build a new one
 @reading = customer.readings.build
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html #new.html.erb  
  end
end
```

My view in the readings folder for creating the new reading is

```
<div class = "page-header">
   <h1> New Readings </h1>
</div>

<%= render 'form_reading' %>
```

And my _form_reading is

```
<%= simple_form_for [@reading.customer, @reading], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal'    } do |f| %>
<%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @reading %>
<%= f.input :customer_id %>
<%= f.input :date_of_reading, :as => :date %>
<%= render_readings_conditionally(f) %>
<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
  <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
              customer_reading_path, :class => 'btn' %> 
</div>
<% end %>
```

However, am troubled, a call to /customers/1/readings/new returns

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"readings"}

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you call to `customer_reading_path` you are not passing customer_id. You can do it as

```
customer_readings_path(@reading.customer)
```

Please note that its **readings** and not **reading** .

Answer (score 0):

customer_reading_path `(:customer_id => <Pass customer ID here>)`

Comment: Thank you, it has worked. Actually i edited it to customer_readings_path